# Discount in the specific product title using keyword ( Woocoommerce )

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

is it possible to create a function that calculates the 10% discount by specifying that in the "Clothing" category all products that contain only the word "shirt" in the title?

Or rather is possible to specify using a word containing in the product title as "shirt".
That is, if products are titled:

- Blue shirt
- Blue jeans
- Red shirt
- White jeans

I have to apply the discount (via keyword "shirt") only to:

- Blue shirt
- Red shirt

It is a somewhat particular request I am aware of, but it was requested by a customer.

Answer (score 0):

try out this plugin hop it's work for you

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-bulk-price-update/

Comment: Useful yes, but it is not possible to specify using a word containing in the product title as "shirt".
That is, if products are titled:

- Blue shirt
- Blue jeans
- Red shirt
- White jeans

I have to apply the discount (via keyword "shirt") only to:
- Blue shirt
- Red shirt